# Anyone uses the google-translate service from the Moodle plugin https://moodle.org/plugins/filter_fulltranslate

Tags: moodle, google-translate

i have installed a plugin in Moodle that is ment to translate textstrings into different (installed) languages.

The installation did work, registering with Google-Cloud and getting an API-Key did work as well. In the (over)load  of information on how to use the google service i found some settings that i adjusted.
But . . . i still get an 403 authorisation error.

The google console shows the attempts to get translations but none is made.

Anyone an idea where i should search for a solution?

Regards,
Jan

Answer (score 0):

The plugin link says it's been superseded

"Content translation filter (superseded)"

https://moodle.org/plugins/filter_fulltranslate

Have you tried the new version?

https://moodle.org/plugins/filter_translations

Comment: I run https://moodle.org/plugins/filter_translations - the problem is a 403, for some reason the authorisation on the google side fails although i can see in the console that requests for translations are made.